# Angular10 - Change multiple css id with onClick event

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, onclick

I am having some trouble trying to change the css of a button with the (click) event. I managed to do it, but the problem is that I have 10 buttons, so I can't depend on one variable in the .ts because once it changes, it will affect all 10 buttons and not just the one which was clicked, so the only thing I thought was having 10 different variables, but it is not quite elegant. Is there any way of doing it a bit cleaner?

Here is what I've got so far:

html:

```
<button (click)="b1 = !b1" class="tarea" [id]="cambiaId(b1)"></button>
<button (click)="b2 = !b2" class="tarea" [id]="cambiaId(b2)"></button>
<button (click)="b3 = !b3" class="tarea" [id]="cambiaId(b3)"></button>
[...]
<button (click)="b10 = !b10" class="tarea" [id]="cambiaId(b10)"></button>
```

ts:

```
export class TareasComponent {
  b1 : boolean = false;
  b2 : boolean = false;
  b3 : boolean = false;
[...]
  b10 : boolean = false;


cambiaId(b : boolean){
    if (b) {
      return "done";
    }else{
      return "todo";
    }
  }
```

Comment: Why do you want to change the id of a button?

Comment: You should toggle class name, not the id of button

Comment: I think the best use here is a template loop. since all the buttons are pretty much the same, you could use *ngFor for it, and I would suggest using an array by index access from the loop to save the states. from there you can use ngClass and css to change styling on click

Answer (score 0):

I think you might have some valid reason to have duplicate id for elements. To do it in performant way in angular would be to do with ngFor and trackby. A sample imlementation is available at [CodeSandbox Implementation](https://codesandbox.io/s/heuristic-glitter-jw2of)

```js
buttons: ButtonType[] = Array(10)
    .fill("todo")
    .map((value, i) => ({ id: i, value }));

  trackById(index: number, button: ButtonType) {
    return button.id;
  }

  buttonClicked(index: number, button: ButtonType) {
    const ret = this.buttons.slice(0);
    ret[index] = {
      ...button,
      value: button.value ? "done" : "todo"
    };
    this.buttons = ret;
  }
```

```html
<ng-container *ngFor="let item of buttons; index as i; trackBy:trackById">
    <button [id]="item.value" (click)="buttonClicked(i, item)" class="tarea">
      {{item.value}}
    </button>
  </ng-container>
```

Comment: Lambo14, as you pass to the function an object, you can simple use: `button.value=button.value=="todo"?"done":"todo"` in your function -it's innecesary make a copy of the array, another way is `this.buttons[index].value=this.buttons[index].value=="todo"?"done":"todo"`

Comment: Yes, that is correct... But, I like keeping things immutable...